# write values to raster table

Tags: arcpy, raster, attribute-table, cursor

I am working with a .tif raster which has an attribute table. I can successfully add a number of extra fields, however I am having problems populating those fields.

When I add the updateCursor part to my code the script runs correctly but the attribute table is empty.

What I want to do is to take the value in the "rv_q20" field and if that is equal to a number write a new given value in "rv_q20s". I tried to pass the values from "rv_q20" between "" (e.g. "5") but encounter the same problem.

I would like to avoid using the arcpy.CalculateField_management

---

```
import arcpy

megaraster = r"E:\GIS Data\Raster1.tif"

#add score fields
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q20s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q50s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q100s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q200s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q500s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q1500s", "SHORT")

arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q20s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q50s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q100s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q200s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q500s", "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q1500s", "SHORT")

#add field descriptions
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q20d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q50d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q100d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q200d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q500d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "rv_q1500d", "TEXT")

arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q20d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q50d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q100d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q200d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q500d", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, "sw_q1500d", "TEXT")

RFscore = "RFscore"
SWscore = "SWscore"

arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, RFscore, "SHORT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, SWscore, "SHORT")

#add field for total score
Totscore = "TotScore"
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, Totscore, "SHORT")

#add field for Risk Level
RiskLevel = "RiskLevel"
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, RiskLevel, "TEXT")

RFscoreName = "RFRetPer"
SWscoreName = "SWRetPer"

arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, RFscoreName, "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(megaraster, SWscoreName, "TEXT")

#call the update cursor to iterate through all the rows

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(megaraster)

for row in rows:
    fldDepth = row.getValue("rv_q20")
    if fldDepth is 1:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 10)
    elif fldDepth is 2:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 11)
    elif fldDepth is 3:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 12)
    elif fldDepth is 4:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 13)
    elif fldDepth is 5:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 14)
    elif fldDepth is 6:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 15)
    else:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 0)
```

Comment: I found the solution myself, I was missing the bit that updates the values. I changed the last part of the code to:

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself, I was missing the bit that updates the values. I changed the last part of the code to:

```
for row in rows:
    fldDepth = row.getValue("rv_q20")
    if fldDepth == 1:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 10)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    elif fldDepth == 2:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 11)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    elif fldDepth == 3:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 12)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    elif fldDepth == 4:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 13)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    elif fldDepth == 5:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 14)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    elif fldDepth == 6:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 15)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    else:
        row.setValue("rv_q20s", 0)
        rows.updateRow(row)
```